Fourier transformation of autocorrelation function
If $g(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} f(y) \bar{f}(y-x) dy,$ where $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N),$ prove that $\hat{g}(y)=|\hat{f}(y)|^2 \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N).$ Also show that $g\in C_0(\mathbb{R}^N).$
Can anyone help me solve this?

Could you define your notations cause I dont uderstand what are $L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$, $\bar{f}$.

$\bar{f}$ means the conjugate and any function $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R^N})$ means $\int_{\mathbb{R^N}} |g| <\infty.$
